# Закодированная строка в POST-запросе

Tags: .net, http, post

Здравствуйте!

Помогите определить, чем (каким методом) закодирована строка, которая передаётся в POST-запросе (пересмотрел известные алгоритмы кодирования строки и либо не нашёл подходящего, либо не понял).

```
    %2FwEPDwUKLTg3NjgwNzkxMA9kFgICAw9kFgYCAQ9kFgICBQ9kFgZmD2QWRgIBDw8WBB4JTWluQW1vdW50B3sUrkf%heoQ
```

Кусок самого запроса (целиком слишком длинный выходит):

```
POST /default.aspx?i=accept HTTP/1.1
Host: 5.45.65.182
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 19261
__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKLTg3NjgwNzkxMA9kFgICAw9kFgYCAQ9kFgICBQ9kFgZmD2QWRgIBDw8WBB4JTWluQW1vdW50B3sUrkfheoQ
```

Comment: base64_decode пробовали?

Comment: Что-то там получается [из base64](http://base64.ru/) после urlDecode:

[скриншот](http://imgur.com/PjCs8K5)

Comment: Да, судя по всему, бейс64, из-за урл-тегов не разглядел + ещё какие-то неведомые символы (видимо, кодировка определённая нужна). Спасибо! Дальше ясно, куда копать.

Answer (score 1):

`__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE` - это признак наличия ASP.NET WebForms.

ViewState - это служебное поле ASP.NET WebForms, в котором сохраняется состояние контролов на момент рендеринга страницы. За счет этого ASP.NET детектит change-события - сравнивет значения пришедшие с формы со значениями из ViewState и вызывает всякие там OnTextChanged. За счет этого же состояния ASP.NET позволяет выбирать данные, например, для гридов, один раз, при первом заходе на страницу, а не при каждом рендеринге. Вобщем, там куча служебной информации о том, что сейчас видно на странице.

Хранится все это в виде дерева объектов, сериализованных в base64. Раньше было полно онлайн и оффлайн декодеров, но сейчас их живых нашел только http://www.binaryfortress.com/ASPNET-ViewState-Helper/Download/. Но ему требуется полная строка, а в вопросе только ее начало.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, какой язык вы используете, пишу на php:

```
echo base64_decode(urldecode("%2FwEPDwUKLTg3NjgwNzkxMA9kFgICAw9kFgYCAQ9kFgICBQ9kFgZmD2QWRgIBDw8WBB4JTWluQW1vdW50B3sUrkf%heoQ"));
```